# How to show plus and minus sign when subtracting two variables:

Tags: php, variables

How to show plus and minus sign when subtracting two variables:Following codes shows -1, that is fine but when the value is positive then it is not showing +sign.

```
$gf=5;
$ga=6;
$gd=$gf-$ga;
echo $gd;
```

Comment: use conditional statements to check whether or not the sum is positive or negative and then simply concatenate the proper symbols. Have you not made any effort to solve this yourself?

Comment: what is your requirement just for showing or anything else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of echo, try this:

```
printf('%+d', $gd);
```

Reference: [printf() string formatting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php#refsect1-function.sprintf-examples)

Comment: How to show here:                                                                             $content.='<td class="team-gd">'.$gd.'</td>';

Comment: What do you mean? If you use the above syntax, it will give you the desired output.

Answer (score 3):

For just display purpose do this

```
$gf=5;
$ga=6;
$gd=$gf-$ga;
if($gd > 0)
{
   echo "+".$gd;
}
else
{
   echo $gd;
}
```